# Bootstrap link within span overlap div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, css-float

I have this simple user profile -https://jsfiddle.net/mt15199/fgogetrh/
I want to pull the envelope icon on the left, so I put it on span element and added a class pull-left but icons dropped and overlapped the container. Without this span element with pull left class the envelope icon and other icon sitting inside of div.

How can I fix this?

```
                    <span class="pull-left"> 
                <a data-original-title="Broadcast Message" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a>
            </span>
```

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/fgogetrh/1/

Comment: Thank you! please add that as an answer :)

Comment: Glad that i could help you :)

Comment: Thank you again man! I can't accept  your answer as of the moment as I need to wait 5 minutes before I accept answer. Have a good day!

Comment: oh..ok sorry for asking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are using `float` don't forget to use `clear` or else element will overlap.

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/fgogetrh/2/)

Use `clearfix` class or `clear:both;` after floated element

use

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

or

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

First example is from bootstrap having same style given in second one.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!

Comment: Of course man, need to wait for 3 minutes more , I'll be gladly accept this once timer went down.